# How to grep a string in a file and output the number next to the string

Tags: sed, grep

I have this output when I grep a string in a file.

```
$ grep "java vm version" dev_server0
F    java vm version   : 6.1.094 25.51-b02
```

I just need the output as `6.1.094` and remove all the other characters/ numbers around it removed. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
grep "java vm version" dev_server0 | awk '{print $6}'
```

`awk` by default splits input line on spaces and 6th field is what you need

For example:

```
$ echo 'F    java vm version   : 6.1.094 25.51-b02' | awk '{print $6}'
6.1.094
```

If you have `grep` with `pcre`, try

```
grep -oP 'java vm version\s*:\s*\K\S+' dev_server0
```

- `java vm version\s*:\s*\K` positive lookbehind this pattern
- `\S+` extract non-space characters

Answer (score 1):

Just printing 6th field:

```
grep "java vm version" dev_server0 | awk '{print $6}'
```

Comment: Isn't that exactly what [Sundeep](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/317671/117549) wrote?

Comment: yes but it was simultaneous .  didnt refresh the page

Comment: Ahhh - I see the original post time, now.

Answer (score 1):

POSIXly:

```
sed -n 's/.*java vm version[[:blank:]:]*\([^[:blank:]]*\).*/\1/p'
```